# How to center cells inside collection view using collection view compositional layout

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following task at work: I need to implement the cinema view where I have a screen and a collection of seats where each row represents a section: [image]

Data is coming from a 2-dimensional array that represents the seats:

```
var seats = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
]
```

The issues is that I can't seem to find how to center the cells inside collection view using compositional layout. Here's the code that manages the layout:

```
private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [weak self] (section, configuration) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            guard let self = self else { return nil }
            
            // get the max seat number
            let max = CGFloat(self.seats.compactMap { $0.max() }.max()!)

            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0 / max),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.5))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            item.contentInsets = .init(top: 2, leading: 2, bottom: 2, trailing: 2)

            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                                                         heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2))

            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.contentInsets = .init(top: 16, leading: 32, bottom: 0, trailing: 32)
            
            return section
        }
        
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.interSectionSpacing = -50
        layout.configuration = config
        
        return layout
    }
```

I managed to implement this behavior using an "old-school" collection view flow layout like this:

[image]

Obviously I can't use methods of Collection View Flow Layout like `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:` to calculate this, so any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does "center the cells inside collection view" mean? Your screen shot looks good, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @matt So last two rows are occupying the whole width of collection view, that's great. But I want rows 0-3 to be placed in the center as they are usually placed at the cinema.

Comment: @matt I also thought about flexible edge spaces but can't seem to find the proper way to implement this. Btw I added an example using conventional flow layout.

Answer (score 5):

Let each row, or at least each set of rows with the same number of items, be its own section, and give the layout a section provider function. The section provider function is given the section number along with an environment object. From that environment object, you can learn the width of the collection view. Now just give the group or section appropriate insets.

To illustrate, I was able to achieve a layout like this (three sections, number of items per section is the section index plus one):

[image]

And I won't keep you in suspense; I'll just show you the code for that layout. It isn't pretty; I used a bunch of hard-coded values. The idea was just to generate the layout so as to show you the general principles. But I'm sure you can see how to adapt this to your own situation:

```
let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
config.scrollDirection = .vertical
let inter = 5 as CGFloat
config.interSectionSpacing = 5
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: { ix, environment in
    let side = 30 as CGFloat
    let cellsz = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(side), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let cell = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: cellsz)
    let groupsz = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(side))
    let count = ix+1
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupsz, subitems: [cell])
    group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(inter)
    let sec = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    let width = environment.container.contentSize.width
    let inset = (width - CGFloat(count)*side - (CGFloat(count)-1)*inter) / 2.0
    sec.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: inset, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
    return sec
}, configuration: config)
```

That's probably not the only way; you could instead, I think, call `NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom` and just lay out the cells manually. But I think this is not a bad solution.

I should also say that I'm not persuaded that a collection view is the best way to get the result you're trying to achieve. You might do better just to lay out the seat views yourself, directly, in code.

Comment: This is also what I am doing, but sometimes my row is larger than the screen so the `inset` is negative, this is fine the position is still correct. If I swipe to the left to scroll and see the elements on the right side of the screen, they are all there. But if I scroll to see the cells on the left side of the screen, they are not there. Because of the negative offset, iOS assumes I don't want those items. Not sure how to overcome this problem yet, if anyone has  seen this happening and has a helpful tip, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem while implementing my own keyboard. My result: [Keyboard images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkyhT.png). This is how I did it without using constants (an improvement of Matt's awesome answer).

```
  private func generateKeyboardLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {

    let groupInset = 3 / UIScreen.main.scale
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
      let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
          widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))
      
      let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
          widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/10),
          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/3)),
        subitems: [item])
      group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: groupInset, leading: groupInset, bottom: groupInset, trailing: groupInset)
      
      let count = Keyboard.getItems(at: keyboardSection).count
      let containerWidth = layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.width
      let groupWidthDimension = group.layoutSize.widthDimension.dimension
      let itemWidth = containerWidth * groupWidthDimension
      let inset = (containerWidth - CGFloat(count) * itemWidth) / 2.0
  
      let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
      section.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: round(inset), bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
      section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
      return section
    }
    return layout
  }
```

**count** represents the number of items per row

```
let count = Keyboard.getItems(at: keyboardSection).count
```

**containerWidth** is the exact width of the view in CGFloat

```
let containerWidth = layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.width
```

**groupWidthDimension** is the width of each group / keyboard tile including the applied insets

```
let groupWidthDimension = group.layoutSize.widthDimension.dimension
```

**itemWidth** gives you the exact size of each keyboard tile

```
let itemWidth = containerWidth * groupWidthDimension
```

**inset** (leading) is calculated based on the difference of the **containerWidth** and the sum of all the items' width and then halved

```
let inset = (containerWidth - CGFloat(count) * itemWidth) / 2.0
section.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: round(inset), bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
```

Comment: I tried this: I get a nice well spaced row of orthogonally scrolling cells with your layout, which isn't bad.  But I was looking for centered rows of equal number of elements ('count'), with vertical scrolling. I don't have a pyramid like the OP does. I want lines of the same length centered in the view containing the collection view. I will see if I can make the adjustments to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom(layoutSize:)` where we can set the frame using `NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItemProvider`.

Set the frame for each item using

```
var customItems = [NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem]()
            for item in 0..<itemCount {
                let frame = CGRect(x: yourCalculatedMargin, y: yPosition, width: layoutSize.widthDimension.dimension, height: layoutSize.heightDimension.dimension)
                customItems.append(NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem(frame: frame))
            }
            return customItems
```

Remember to calculate the yPosition too for moving on to next line